# Sending form data to page nested in div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

This is my third attempt to find an answer to this question, every other time I was downvoted for one reason or another.  So I try this again.  I am attempting to send data from a hidden input within a form via ajax.  The hidden input gets its value from a php script.  Now I can not seem to pull the hidden input value  on the receiving page.  Now the form I am sending from is generated and propagated within php as is the ajax that fires to send the form to the other page.

When I attempt to call the info from the form on the receiving page it does not seem to receive the data from the first page.  The reason I assume this is I get no errors and it will not display the data but it does fire the echo that is located before the fetch array.

Here is the code for the first page.  It works in all aspects with what I am trying to do except for the form sending portion.  I am leaving a lot out but the ajax and form portions are in there.

```
<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","base","password","util");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {






        echo"




        <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
      $('#" . $row['id'] ."').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/pages/receivingpage.php',
        data: $(\"f2\").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(\"#content-disp\").html(d);
}
    });
  });
 });//end document ready
</script>


        <div id=\"covera\">

        <div id=\"holder\" class=\"holder\">


<div id=\"disp\" class=\"disp\">

<div class=\"click diagonal panel\">
    <div id=\"" . $row['id'] ."\"  class=\"front\">
    <form id=\"" . $row['recipe'] ."\" name=\"f2\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"recipe\" value=\"" . $row['recipe'] ."\">
        <h2>
        " . $row['recipe'] ."<br></h2>
     <img src=\"http://localhost/img/" . $row['image'] ."\" alt=\"Recipe Image\" style=\"width:150px;height:100px;\">

    </form> 
    </div>


    <div class=\"back\">
        <div class=\"pad\">
            <h2>" . $row['recipe'] ."</h2>

            <p>" . $row['id'] ."</p>
            <p>" . $row['id'] ."</p>
                        <p>Number of Servings " . $row['servings'] ."</p>
            <p>Appx. Cooking Time: " . $row['cooking'] ." Minutes</p>
            <p>Numer of Calories: " . $row['calories'] ."</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>






            </div>

            </div>";


}

  mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Here is the receiving page.  It loads but only displays the echo.  If I remove the WHERE within the SELECT statement it displays all the database results(not what is desired).

```
<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","base","password","util");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$r = $_POST["f2"]['recipe'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE recipe ='".$r."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo "  2 ";



while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {






echo "  " . $row['recipe'] ." ";


}

  mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending form result to page in another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683605/sending-form-result-to-page-in-another-div)

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question, clean up the original to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try posting serialized data using id instead of the name of the form. See below the example code.

```
data: $(\"#f2\").serialize(),
```

Hope this will help you.

See below updated working code.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

**page1.php**

```
</script>
<?php

    $rows[0]['id'] = 1;
    $rows[0]['recipe'] = "Veg Rec";
    $rows[0]['cooking'] = "Hot cooking";
    $rows[0]['calories'] = 1000;
    $rows[0]['image'] = "image.png";
    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    # code...
    echo"




        <div id=\"covera\">

        <div id=\"holder\" class=\"holder\">


<div id=\"disp\" class=\"disp\">

<div class=\"click diagonal panel\">
    <div id=\"" . $row['id'] ."\"  class=\"front\">
    <form id2=\"" . $row['recipe'] ."\" id=\"f2\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"recipe\" value=\"" . $row['recipe'] ."\">
        <h2>
        " . $row['recipe'] ."<br></h2>
     <img src=\"http://localhost/img/" . $row['image'] ."\" alt=\"Recipe Image\" style=\"width:150px;height:100px;\">

    </form> 
    </div>


    <div class=\"back\">
        <div class=\"pad\">
            <h2>" . $row['recipe'] ."</h2>

            <p>" . $row['id'] ."</p>
            <p>" . $row['id'] ."</p>
                        <p>Number of Servings " . $row['servings'] ."</p>
            <p>Appx. Cooking Time: " . $row['cooking'] ." Minutes</p>
            <p>Numer of Calories: " . $row['calories'] ."</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>






            </div>

            </div>



<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
      $('#" . $row['id'] ."').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page2.php',
        data: $(\"#f2\").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(\"#content-disp\").html(d);
}
    });
  });
 });//end document ready
</script>


            ";


}

?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);


?>
```

Comment: I just attempted using the id instead changing the ajax then changing it on the receiving page.  It presented with the same result as before

Comment: Sorry I tried using the formating but didnt quite get it

After messing around with it some more I am fairly confident the problem is that the $_POST[#f2] on the receiving page is not receiving the data from the hidden input form.  So the problem is  here somewhere as you are guessing



        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/pages/receivingpage.php',
        data: $(\"#f2\").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(\"#content-disp\").html(d);
}

or here

<form id=\"f2\" name=\"f2\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"" . $row['id'] ."\">
    </form>'

Comment: you have to change the ajax code as well. If you will not change the ajax code, changes made in the form ID will not help you. If you fear  you will have to make a lot of changes in the receiving page. Than its true you have to make changes in the receving page if want things to run as expected.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.  In the code I am working with now I have done so

Comment: Let me rephrase what I see going on so maybe you all can understand the issue I am seeing a little better. The ajax and form is generated for each row in a given db.  The hidden input/form is located within a div.  The ajax is specific for each result displayed.  When I click on the generated div the ajax should send the data to the receiving page which is loaded in another div.  Something is lost in translation between the first page and receiving page.

Comment: Unfortunatly it is not, I am still returning nothing in the post result with the receiving page

Comment: check out my updated answer. Its a working code with the solution I am talking about.

Comment: I just tried your code, it works as in it displays the first row of the table regardless of which entry I click.  I believe that the form having a static id of #f2 , as the ajax is calling for the #f2 form when clicked.  I have attempted to use the a row variable " . $row['id'] ." as the form id/name and as the ajax         data: $(\"" . $row['in'] ."\").serialize(),  It returns Array ( ).  When I use your method it returns an array though.  Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: Okie, so i got it working.  I will post the updated code above.  Basically, it seems if I want to use a row call variable as an id to be called in ajax I need to add an arburtrary f_ or what ever one chooses.  So data: $(\"f_" . $row['in'] ."\").serialize(),   and <form id=\f_" . $row['in'] ."\">

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: More than happy to help you @Soul-Burn.